# type a React component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following SSCCE:

```
function just_accept(x: React.ComponentType<any>): void {
}


class A extends React.Component<any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {return <span>foo</span>;}
}

just_accept(A); // <-- this is the offending line in the typescript message
```

That gives me the following typescript error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'ComponentType'.   Type 'typeof A' is not assignable to
> type 'ComponentClass<any, any>'.
> Type 'A' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<any, any, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and
> 2 more.

Declaring the parameter `x` to be of type `React.ComponentClass<any, any>` makes no difference.

Comment: Does `just_accept(A.name);` works? Probably not? I am just guessing :P your function expects a `React.ComponentType<any>`, but you pass a `React.Component<any>`

Answer (score 0):

This was due to having:

```
const React = require('react');
```

Once this was replaced by:

```
import React from 'react';
```

... things work as expected.